# VS Code tool Problem - Displaying a blank space in dual monitors

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have used VS Code for 1 month and suddenly it shows empty(black) space in the second monitor

[image]

When I click this empty space, then VS Code is closed like when I click the minimize button in chrome.
I am using dual monitors and this problem only happens in the second monitor. In the first monitor, there is no empty space and worked fine. Could you help me to solve this problem..?

Comment: Seems to be a resolution issue. What OS is this?

Comment: I am using Win10 and found out that ctrl + F5 also does not work in vs code...

Comment: Have you set the windows task bar to appear on both screens?